# Regex limit number of a character in a pattern

Tags: python, regex

whole_string =

```
Section 1.1 Some String.........................10

Section 1.2 Some Other String...................11
```

I only want to get <Some String> out. <Some String> may contain `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, some non-word characters (e.g. `()-,&`), and also dots. But the number of dots would be less than 3.

I am trying `r'Section 1.1 \[A-Za-z0-9,.()&\\s\]\[.\]+\\d+$'`, but it would give me the whole_string.

I am thinking about a way to add a limit on the occurence of dots, like `r'Section 1.1 \[A-Za-z0-9,.**{,3}**()&\\s\]\[.\]+\\d+$'`, but it does not work.

Anyone have any idea on it?

Comment: Can the string contain whitespace such as spaces? If so, will the tokens prior to <Some String> always be `Section 1.1`, or at `Section digit.digit`?

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your question to add the two examples in your comment to a deleted answer. They will make your question a lot clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the pattern that you tried and the example strings, I think it should end matching dots followed by digits.

In that case you can use a capture group:

```
\bSection 1\.1\s+([^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){0,3})\.+\d+$
```

**Explanation**

- `\bSection 1\.1` Match the word `Section` and then `1.1`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^.]+` Match 1+ chars other than `.`
  - `(?:\.[^.]+){0,3}` Repeat 0-3 times matching `.` followed by 1+ chars other than a `.`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.+\d+` Match 1+ dots and 1+ digits (use `\.*` to match optional dots)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FuQbe3/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ykWQH2)

Example with `re.findall` which returns the capture group 1 value:

```
import re

pattern = r"\bSection 1\.1\s+([^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){0,3})\.+\d+$"

s = ("Section 1.1 Some String.........................10\n"
    "Section 1.2 Some Other String...................11\n"
    "Section 1.1 I want to catch Som.e Str.i.ng..9\n"
    "Section 1.1 I want to catch Som.e..9\n"
    "Section 1.1 I want to catch Som.e Str.i.ng9\n"
    "Section 1.1 but not So.m.e Str.i.ng.9")
    
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['Some String', 'I want to catch Som.e Str.i.ng', 'I want to catch Som.e']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic version that can be customised a bit to better fit your needs

```
"(?:Section \d+\.\d+ )([\sA-Za-z0-9()\-,&\.]*?)(?=\.{4})"gm
```

This will match both `Some String` and `Some Other String`, and if you want to specifically match to `Section 1.1`, change the `(?:Section \d+\.\d+)` to `(?:Section 1.1)`.

If you use `re.findall`, only `Some String` and `Some Other String` will be the result. If you use `re.search`, you will need to specify `match.group(1)` to get the result.

It works by matching `Section digit.digit` in a non-capture group (which is why it doesnt appear in group 1), matching the characters you mentioned (although space is not included in your text, I included it in the regex to account for the space in `Some String`), and looks for 4 `.` characters ahead of it to end the match. Since the 4 `.` characters are a lookahead, it is not included in the match.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a violation of the DRY principle, but I'm not aware of any way of constraining the number of occurrences of a single character while not limiting the others:

```
Section 1\.1 [A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]+[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*[.]+\d+$
```

This is just repeating `[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]` (the dot is not included) with three intercalated `[.]?`. Note that the first occurrence of `[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]` needs to happen at least once (`+`) but the other ones can never occur (`*`).

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/eegRMn/1).

Of course, you could programmatically build the pattern for any desired number of dots:

```
def build_pattern(section, dots):
    pattern = r'Section 1\.' + str(section) + ' [A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]+'\
              + '[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*' * dots\
              + '[.]+\d+$'
    return pattern

build_pattern(1, 3)
#Section 1\.1 [A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]+[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*[.]?[A-Za-z0-9,()&\s]*[.]+\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match non-dot-characters optionally followed by up to two groups of a dot and non-dot-characters:

```
(?<=Section 1\.1 )[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){,2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qFuPgb/4